# I am not getting email from this https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-people-api

I am not getting response https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email since I have set scopes in my app on google cloud. I am receiving other info like picture first name, gender etc from https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo but not email. Help me in this

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example].  Im not exactly sure what you expect to get back from https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email   I have never seen this endpoint do you have documentation on it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not guarantee that the user info end point will always return the claims.

To get user profile data you should be using the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22emailAddresses%22%7D).

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
```

Response

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/1170475532672775346",
  "etag": "%EgUBCS43PhoEAQIFByIMR3BzQkR2cnI1ZGc9",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "verified": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "1172004755326727753"
        },
        "sourcePrimary": true
      },
      "value": "xxxx@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      --compressed
```

## from comments

> People API has not been used in project 946655775285 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting

This error message is very common. It means that you are trying to use an api in the project which you have not enabled.

Go to google cloud console using the link they have supplied, go to library and enable the google people api.

[image]

once you have enabled it

[image]

It should work.

Comment: i receive 403 in response for the above link you provided.

Comment: 403 what?  what is the full error message?

Comment: here is the error{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "People API has not been used in project 946655775285 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/overview?project=946655775285 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",

Comment: I have edited my answer you need to enable the People api as instructed in the error message.

Comment: https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses&key=AIzaSyAubL3Kyed_FfXzYJMDMTJyHzkwE4k4Clc
this is the above link with my api key for testing but still it is yielding no results. What to do now?
here is new error now:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

Comment: i have enabled people api according to your instructions also